# Android APK Expansion: ZIP Parameters

Tags: android, zip, apk

My team and I are publishing an Android app on Google Play.  Due to the size of our app (50mb+), we had to include expansion files.  Currently, we're having issues with the expansion files.  Specifically, the expansion files are not being recognized by the app during testing.

We suspect that the issue may be with how we are ZIP-ing our expansion files.  The Android documentation gives clear instructions about naming conventions, but we cannot find information regarding ZIP options and parameters.

What specific options and parameters should we be using when we ZIP our expansion files? Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "not being recognized"? Do you see any error?

Comment: Hello, Sam.  The key assets in our expansion file are a PNG sequence. This PNG sequence is supposed to create short videos within the app. However, when we launch the app, the PNG sequence does not play when it's supposed to.  We can hear the audio of this PNG sequence / video, but not the visuals.

We do not get an error message, which is what's making this especially difficult to fix.

Comment: It's almost impossible to help if we can't see any error/stacktrace/exception. In order to read from ZIP Expansion you will need an `InputStream` to read the files. If there is any problem with that, it'll give you error or something. Try to debug your code and at least narrow down the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry for the lack of helpful information for the core issue. That is why the question I asked concerned the parameters and options we should use when creating a ZIP of the expansion files, since our current suspicion is that we're ZIP-ing up the package wrong.  Are there any online resources that explain things like how much compression we should be using in the ZIP, and other details, when creating an expansion file for Google Play?

Comment: The last time I used Zip Expansion there was a bug with compressed file. So I had to make the Zip file without any compression. I don't know if it's still there but you may try it to see if it solves your problem. But I highly doubt it.

Answer (score 1):

Like Sam said in one of his comments, we went with 0 compression in the ZIP we created.

The issue has been fixed, and the 0 compression may have been part of the solution.  The real problem, it turned out, had to do with how we were naming our expansion file package.

Here was the issue:  During Google Play Alpha channel testing, our expansion files were not appearing at all within the OBB folder when downloaded onto devices that were running Android 4.4.2.  For devices running earlier versions of Android (4.1 to 4.3, specifically), the expansion files were appearing in the OBB folder, but our app wasn't reading them.

It turned out that the expansion files were corrupted.  We think that the biggest cause of this problem had to do with how we were naming the expansion file ZIP.

We ZIPed the expansion file package using 0 compression.  Originally, the ZIP we created was named this:

```
main.(CODE VERSION).(ANY DOMAIN).(YOUR COMPANY).(YOUR PROJECT).zip
```

For example: `main.1.com.company.project.zip`

As you can see, we did not include "obb" in the file name.  After Google Play converted our expansion files to an OBB, the expansion files would be corrupted.

We then went with this name for the file expansion package:

```
main.(CODE VERSION).(ANY DOMAIN).(YOUR COMPANY).(YOUR PROJECT).obb.zip
```

For example: `main.1.com.company.project.obb.zip`

After Google Play converted the expansion file zip to an obb, it came out as:

```
main.1.com.company.project.obb
```

When we uploaded that ZIP to Google Play, the OBB we got back during Alpha channel testing worked.  Our expansion files were appearing correctly in the devices' OBB folders, and our app was reading the assets.

Has anyone else used a similar naming convention as the one we used to finally get their obb working?

Comment: This is pretty odd, as I have just created an app with an expansion file, and named it like you did with your first zip file (and how it's outlined in the docs) and had no issue with Google Play corrupting it. I'd advise people NOT to name the file .obb.zip, as Google Play *should* convert it correctly.